# Debugging multi threaded environment in .net

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging

I have an application that uses background workers.
There are places that a background worker starts from a timer tick event.
How can I prevent the code from jumping in debug to the timer tick?

Should I manage the timer in another thread??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about running the application inside of Visual Studio, use the [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute to instruct the compiler to not step into that specific method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I dont get your question - what do you mean by "jumping in debug". Maybe conditional breakpoints could work for you?

Regards
--Jocke